# When I see you next

Tags: adverbs

There is a sentence in a textbook: "I can answer any questions you've got when I see you next." What does "see you next" means? Is it a contraction of "see you next time"?

Comment: There's no need to assume an "unspecified" noun ***time*** here. The word ***next*** is a straighforward adverb modifying ***see***, which could equally well have been placed *before* the verb: *...when **I next see** you*. Or more "poetically", it can even come before the subject: *...when **next I see** you*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I see you next = The next time I meet you.

Note that it isn't actually a literal usage in this case. In the context of a classroom situation (for example), it means 'when the class meets again for a lesson'. If a teacher says "I'll explain it when I see you next", they mean 'in the next lesson'. If they happen to meet the students in a different context, such as in the cafeteria after the lesson, the teacher isn't suddenly going to start explaining the point there.